# Why aren't objects being pushed to this vector (when it's a member of a struct)?

Tags: c++

I have the following code, which loops through an array of `menuoptions` and on each iteration,  creates a `ScaledRect` object and pushes it to a vector. This vector is a member of a struct.

I have verified that the ScaledRect is created with the correct values, yet when I print back the contents of the `regions` vector ( in the second loop ), the loop never terminates and the values are garbage.

```
class ScaledRect : public Rect
{
public:
    ScaledRect(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
};
ScaledRect::ScaledRect(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2):
    _x1(x1), _y1(y1), _x2(x2), _y2(y2){}

// ScaledRect doesn't have copy constructor, but Rect does
Rect::Rect( const Rect &rect)
{
x1=rect.x1; y1=rect.y1; x2=rect.x2; y2=rect.y2; bClean=KD_FALSE;
}

typedef struct
{
    std::vector<ScaledRect> regions;
}interface;

void PushRegions( interface * myself )
{
    int i = 0;
    while(menuoptions[i].callback != -1 )
    {
        ScaledRect s = 
          ScaledRect(menuoptions[i].x1, 
                     menuoptions[i].y1,
                     menuoptions[i].x2, 
                     menuoptions[i].y2);            
        myself->regions.push_back( s );
        i++;
    }

    std::vector<ScaledRect>::iterator iter = myself->regions.begin();
    std::vector<ScaledRect>::iterator done = myself->regions.end();

    while(iter != done)
    {
        iter->Dump();
        iter++;
    }
}
```

EDIT
Please note - I've just edited - the memory for `theinterface` is created and I do actually pass in the address of `theinterface` to this function. (However, I have simplified those two lines here - what actually happens is that `PushRegions` gets called via a ptr to a function, on a piece of newly allocated memory the size of an `interface` ).

I can't post all of the code here - but minimally its:

```
Func pfunc = GetPFuncForInterfaceObj();
size_t  numbytes = GetSizeForInterfaceObj();
char memory = new char[numbytes];
pfunc(memory);
```

`pfunc` ends up being `PushRegions` and `memory` ends up being passed as an `interface`.

When I push the `ScaledRect` object to a `vector` declared at the top of `PushRegions()` it works. Has anyone got any ideas why?

Comment: Note `interface` doesn't need to be and shouldn't be a typedef.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is utterly wrong:

```
size_t  numbytes = GetSizeForInterfaceObj();
char memory = new char[numbytes];
pfunc(memory);
```

Even if we "fix" it:

```
size_t  numbytes = GetSizeForInterfaceObj();
char* memory = new char[numbytes]; // note pointer
pfunc((interface*)memory); // and cast
```

Your object has never been constructed, so the vector is in a garbage state. (Using the object leads to undefined behavior.)

No, `interface` may not have a constructor *explicitly* defined, but there is an implicit constructor, and it's there for a reason. It needs to construct the members. You can use "placement new" (by including `<new>`) to construct an object by placing it at a memory location:

```
size_t  numbytes = GetSizeForInterfaceObj();
char* memory = new char[numbytes]; // note pointer
pfunc(new (memory) interface); // and CREATE
```

Now you're using a valid object.

---

I'll assume there's a good reason for using pointers at all, let alone a manually constructed object. That said, your code does too much. It both *manages* a resource, and *uses* one; pick one or the other.

That is:

```
struct interface_obj
{
    interface_obj() :
    mMemory(GetSizeForInterfaceObj()),
    mInterface(new (&mMemory[0]) interface)
    {}

    ~interface_obj()
    {
        mInterface->~interface(); // destruct
    }

    interface* get() const
    {
        return mInterface;
    }

private:
    // noncopyable for now, easy to add
    interface_obj(const interface_obj&);    
    interface_obj& operator=(const interface_obj&);

    // again, with the vector we use a resource (dynamic buffer),
    // not manage one.
    std::vector<char> mMemory;
    interface* mInterface;
};
```

Much cleaner:

```
interface_obj obj;
pfunc(obj.get());
```

And it will be released *no matter what*. (Your code wouldn't in the face of exceptions, without messy try-catch blocks and other nonsense.) Again, preferable is to not have this kind of allocation in the first place.

Comment: is there a way to discover what type I need to pass to `pfunc(new (memory) XXXX);` at runtime? `interface` could be any type defined by a user of my system. It won't always be `interface`. However, I can ask users to register types somehow.

Comment: @BeeBand: That sounds like a separate question to me. (And when you ask, do give the "bigger picture". *How* should it work, not the step you think you should take, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to be initializing `i` in the `PushRegions()` function. Are you sure it starts at 0?

**Follow-up to your edits**:

> what actually happens is that PushRegions gets called via a ptr to a function, on a piece of newly allocated memory the size of an interface

What does this mean? Are you actually invoking the `interface` constructor?

**Follow up to your comment**:

Yes, there is a (compiler-generated) constructor. The `std::vector` data member has a default constructor and is invoked by the compiler-generated constructor for `interface`. When you allocate the right amount of memory, without invoking the constructor, you get an uninitialized `std::vector`!

This explains why your loop never terminates and garbage results: you're using an uninitialized object, which results in **undefined behavior**.

Comment: no, there's no constructor for `interface`. Please see my last edit.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing the rest of `ScaledRect` - does it have a working copy constructor and assignment operator?  What does `Dump` do?

Especailly - why is `i` uninitialized?  Is this (all) the (current) code?

Comment: @BeeBand - I still don't see anywhere that `i` is inited in `PushRegions`... That would make the `while(menuoptions[i].callback != -1 )` code behave unpredictably for sure.

Comment: Yes sorry - that's a typo. There is other init code in there that I omitted so I've entered a rough version of my function. Fixing my question.